# Preventing a js file from being called twice

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to put a variable in a javascript file so that it increments whenever the file is called (like a `static` var in Java)? I want to use it to prevent calling a js file twice. Or, is there another way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by calling it twice? Having two pages on the same website reference the same javascript file?

Comment: Have you considered using a full JS module system like requireJS or the one in the Dojo toolkit?

Comment: im actually already using YUI library, but dont know if i can use it for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var checkit = window.check_var;

if(checkit === undefined){ //file never entered. the global var was not set.
    window.check_var = 1;
}
else {
    alert('FILE WAS CALLED ALREADY!');
}
```